# ORA-00939: too many arguments for function in CASE Statement

Tags: sql, oracle, syntax, arguments, substr

I'm getting the `ORA-00939: too many arguments for function` error from my case statement.

I have tried splitting it up into multiple `CASE` statements but still get the same error.

```
CASE WHEN l.fridge_door_modela_id = 'II-SH' THEN 'IW' 
     WHEN l.fridge_door_modela_id = 'IIC-SH' THEN 'IW' 
     WHEN l.fridge_door_modela_id = 'CD' THEN 'RPFX' 
     WHEN l.fridge_door_modela_id LIKE 'EXCR%' THEN SUBSTR(fridge_door_modela_id, 0, INSTR(fridge_door_modela_id, 'EXCR'),1)
     WHEN l.fridge_door_modela_id LIKE 'EX%' THEN SUBSTR(fridge_door_modela_id, 0, INSTR(fridge_door_modela_id, 'EX'),1) 
     WHEN l.fridge_door_modela_id LIKE '%-%' THEN SUBSTR(fridge_door_modela_id, 0, INSTR(fridge_door_modela_id, '-'),1) 
     ELSE 'CHECK CODE' 
     END AS Division
```

Comment: Your `SUBSTR()` calls have four arguments.  Last I checked, the function only took three.  If you provide sample data and desired results, someone might be able to help you get the right code.

Comment: If you execute it in `SQL*Plus` then you will see the error at exact place. `SUBSTR` takes 3 arguments, the correct syntax is `SUBSTR( string, start_position [, length ] )`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> SUBSTR(fridge_door_modela_id, 0, INSTR(fridge_door_modela_id, 'EXCR'),1)

- The above syntax for **SUBSTR** is incorrect. The correct syntax is:

  ```
  SUBSTR( string, start_position [, length ] )
  ```
- Also, the index of `substr` starts from `1` and not `0`.

Executing it in **SQL*Plus** shows  the exact error clearly, see the following **error**:

```
SQL> WITH DATA AS(
  2  SELECT 'abcdEXCRijkl' fridge_door_modela_id FROM dual
  3  )
  4  SELECT SUBSTR(fridge_door_modela_id, 0, INSTR(fridge_door_modela_id, 'EXCR'),1)
  5  FROM DATA;
SELECT SUBSTR(fridge_door_modela_id, 0, INSTR(fridge_door_modela_id, 'EXCR'),1)
                                                                             *
ERROR at line 4:
ORA-00939: too many arguments for function


SQL>
```

Using proper **syntax**:

```
SQL> WITH DATA AS(
  2  SELECT 'abcdEXCRijkl' fridge_door_modela_id FROM dual
  3  )
  4  SELECT SUBSTR(fridge_door_modela_id, 1, INSTR(fridge_door_modela_id, 'EXCR', 1, 1)-1)
  5  FROM DATA;

SUBS
----
abcd

SQL>
```